Prevent Mobile Keyboard but still allow Cursor Interaction
this question seems to have been asked several times but I didn't yet find a definitive solution. I'm building a mobile-friendly calculator component with React and shadcn.
Here is the basic structure
 <div className="w-full max-w-md mx-auto p-4 rounded-lg">
            <Input
                type="text"
                value={input}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
                className="w-full mb-4 text-left text-lg font-mono text-black dark:text-white cursor-text"
                aria-label="Calculator input"
                id='calculator-input'
                inputMode="none"
            />
            {error && (
                <Alert variant="destructive" className="mb-4">
                    <AlertCircle className="h-4 w-4"/>
                    <AlertDescription>{error}</AlertDescription>
                </Alert>
            )}
            <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-2">
                {buttons.map((btn) => (
                    <Button
                        key={btn}
                        onClick={() => handleButtonClick(btn)}
                        className="h-12"
                        useGlobalStyles={false}
                        variant={buttonVariants[btn] || 'default'}
                        aria-label={btn}
                    >
                        {btn === 'Backspace' ? <Delete className="h-4 w-4"/> :
                            btn === 'Enter' ? <ArrowRight className="h-4 w-4 text-black dark:text-white"/> :
                                btn}
                    </Button>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>

Button logic that adds/removes values at cursor position
const handleButtonClick = (value: string) => {
        setError(null)
        if (value === 'Enter') {
            handleSubmit()
        } else if (value === 'Backspace') {
            setInput(prev => {
                const inputElement = document.getElementById('calculator-input') as HTMLInputElement;
                const cursorPosition = inputElement.selectionStart || 0;
                const newValue = (prev || '').toString().slice(0, cursorPosition - 1) + (prev || '').toString().slice(cursorPosition);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    inputElement.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition - 1, cursorPosition - 1);
                }, 0);
                return newValue;
            })
            setIsEvaluated(false)
        } else if (value === '=') {
            if (isEvaluated) {
                handleSubmit()
            } else {
                handleEvaluate()
            }
        } else {
            setInput(prev => {
                const inputElement = document.getElementById('calculator-input') as HTMLInputElement;
                const cursorPosition = inputElement.selectionStart || 0;
                const newValue = (prev || '').toString().slice(0, cursorPosition) + value + (prev || '').toString().slice(cursorPosition);
                setTimeout(() => {
                    inputElement.setSelectionRange(cursorPosition + value.length, cursorPosition + value.length);
                }, 0);
                return newValue;
            });
            setIsEvaluated(false)
        }
    }

Using inputMode="none" doesn't seem to stop the mobile keyboard, any solutions for this would be appreciated. Also, any pointers on more elegant logic for the cursor interaction would also be appreciated.
Thanks
